# maas juju bootstrap fails

Tags: juju, maas

I have a maas server and 6 mass client machines (2 Dell compute servers and 4 HP storage servers).  All 6 clients are declared, commissioned, started, and stopped.  None of them seems to want to wake up on lan. (I have to run down to the machine room and push power buttons to wake them up.)  After the maas stop command, they are left up and running, but are in the "Ready" state.

juju bootstrap --show-log produces:

2014-10-31 00:57:50 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:37 running juju [1.20.11-trusty-amd64 gc]

2014-10-31 00:57:55 INFO juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:48 bootstrapping environment "maas"

2014-10-31 00:57:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:187 filtering tools by released version

2014-10-31 00:57:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:87 reading tools with major.minor version 1.20

2014-10-31 00:57:55 INFO juju.environs.tools tools.go:98 filtering tools by series: trusty

2014-10-31 00:57:56 INFO juju.utils http.go:59 hostname SSL verification enabled

2014-10-31 00:58:01 INFO juju.utils http.go:59 hostname SSL verification enabled

2014-10-31 00:58:07 INFO juju.utils http.go:59 hostname SSL verification enabled

2014-10-31 00:58:12 INFO juju.utils http.go:59 hostname SSL verification enabled

2014-10-31 00:58:19 INFO juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:60 newest version: 1.20.11

2014-10-31 00:58:19 INFO juju.environs.bootstrap bootstrap.go:88 picked bootstrap tools

version: 1.20.11

Launching instance

2014-10-31 00:58:21 WARNING juju.provider.maas environ.go:434 picked arbitrary tools &{1.20.11-trusty-amd64 https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.20.11-trusty-amd64.tgz bf40f7f107aa57023e7a3941aadb1f87ca43096d6c6211ae2838bec99caf8886 8112488}

- /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-36b1f146-5964-11e4-b15a-a4badbed0f5c/

Waiting for address

Attempting to connect to esxi05.maas:22

Attempting to connect to esxi05.maas:22

Attempting to connect to 10.20.0.10:22

2014-10-31 01:28:21 ERROR juju.provider.common bootstrap.go:122 bootstrap failed: waited for 30m0s without being able to connect: /var/lib/juju/nonce.txt does not exist

Stopping instance...

Bootstrap failed, destroying environment

2014-10-31 01:28:21 INFO juju.provider.common destroy.go:15 destroying environment "maas"

2014-10-31 01:28:21 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 waited for 30m0s without being able to connect: /var/lib/juju/nonce.txt does not exist

Do the clients need to be Pxe booted when juju tries to bootstrap?

Can I continue to do a juju deploy without having juju "reinstall the os on the clients"?

Comment: I see in the auth.log on the client machine that cycling with successfully logging in with ssh to ubuntu@host and then logging out.  How do I find out what it is attempting to do?  What is it failing on?  Does juju log this kind of detail somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Juju Bootstrap process is timing out. What you need to do is to increase the timeout in "/home/user/.juju/environments.yaml" file. Search for "bootstrap-timeout: 1800" and increase the value to 2500.

Alos, please make sure that your Power and ssh settings are right.

***Do the clients need to be Pxe booted ...?***

Make sure that your nodes are in "ready" state and not in "allocated" or in any other state.

***Can I continue to do a juju deploy without having juju "reinstall the os on the clients"?***

No, you can't. Juju deploy will fail without successfull Juju bootstrap.

Comment: The clients are pxe booted, commissioned, and powered back down waiting for maas to wake them up.  I start the bootstrap and maas wakes the machine up and I can ssh into it and watch the /var/log/auth.log as juju ssh's into the machine and immediately logs back out.  I have verified that both machines are in sync with the same ntp server.  I have tried switching to a different project name.  Nothing seems to work except wiping the maas server and reintalling from ISO.  Any other ideas of where to look for clues?